# Webkit checkbox default value is null?

Tags: javascript, safari, webkit

When using a WebKit browser (Chrome or Safari), if I try to get the default value of a checkbox, it returns "". However, the same javascript in Firefox or IE will return "on".

So lets say I have this checkbox on a page:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkDefaultValue">
```

I use this javascript to return all "input" elements on a page

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
```

Then I go through a loop that gets the value like this

```
elems[i].getAttribute('value')
```

When elems[i] is that checkbox, in Chrome or Safari it returns "", but Firefox or IE it returns "on".

Is there any way to use Javascript to return the "on" value in Safari or Chrome? In Chrome I use a jquery call that uses .val() and that actually returns "on", but I need a way to do this using Javascript in Safari.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I'm actually looking for the "value" attribute specifically since the "value" of a checkbox can be anything, like "cat" or "bike".

Comment: have you tried making the value attribute of this control value="on"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [checked](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-checked) instead to see if a checkbox or radio input is selected.

If what you really want to do is get the `value` attribute, and not see if the checkbox is selected, then you need to [set a value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-value-INPUT) for the checkbox first. If nothing is set then you getting `null` is the normal behavior.

You can also replicate the Firefox and IE behavior by assigning `on` yourself as a default value:

```
var myVal = elems[i].getAttribute('value');
if(myVal === null)
    myVal = 'on';
```

Comment: I'm actually looking for the "value" attribute specifically since the "value" of a checkbox can be anything, like "cat" or "bike".

Comment: @sbonkosk You need to set a value for the checkbox first. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-value-INPUT

Comment: Yeah I saw that link, but since FF and IE return "on" using the same Javascript, I want to know if there's some way to get that same "on" value in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on non-standard functionality. Why do you want to get that `on`? If you really want it you can hardcode it to be `on` when `elems[i].getAttribute('value') === null`.

Comment: @Alin Purcaru The tool Im working on allows users to set and test element attributes. It's used within a company and many tests have been written already for IE and FF because they were the only 2 supported by the tool. Now that Chrome and Safari will be supported I need to allow the same tests to pass in all browsers, without having to rewrite old tests. If a user was to set the "value" attribute to "", then returning "on" if elems[i].getAttribute('value') === null wouldnt work.

Comment: @sbonkosk Notice that I used an identity operator there (`"" === null` is `false`). If `getAttribute('value')` returns `null` it means that the `value` attribute is not set at all and you may safely assign a default value for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's because `elems[i].getAttribute('value')` is not what you should be using to get the state of a checkbox.

Try using `elems[i].getAttribute('checked')` or just `elems[i].checked` to get the state.
By the way, `elems[i].getAttribute('value')` can be shortened to just `elems[i].value`.

---

Just read your comment on another answer...

Here's the source for the `.val()` statement from the jQuery repo:

```
getVal = function(elem)
{
  var type = elem.type, val = elem.value;

  if (type === "radio" || type === "checkbox")
  {
    val = elem.checked;
  } else if (type === "select-multiple") {
    val = elem.selectedIndex > -1 ? jQuery.map( elem.options, function( elem ) {return elem.selected;}).join("-"):"";
  } else if (elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "select") {
    val = elem.selectedIndex;
  }

  return val;
}
```

That is pretty simple JavaScript, and you can just omit the `.map()` function.

---

Also, why not just test for the existence of the `value` property?

```
function niceValue(element)
{
  if (element.value != '')
  {
    return element.value;
  } elseif (element.checked) {
    if (element.checked)
    {
      return 'on';
    } else {
      return 'off';
    }
  }
}
```

Good luck!